# PHP: Loading gzipped javascript files

Tags: php, javascript, file, gzip

Is it a good idea to concatenate a set of 20-30 .js files into one big file, compress this file with gzip, save it as something like somebigjsfile.js.gz, then load it like this with `<script type="text/javascript" src="somebigjsfile.js.gz"></script>` ?

This file would be generated again when at least one of the .js files have been modified (checking that with php's filemtime).

Also if it's relevant, this is for a public app.

Comment: The web server should be configured to serve gzipped content automatically. Other than that, connecting JS files sounds like a good idea - although I'm not sure how you want to trigger updating the file?

Comment: yes - seems you have it figured out.

Comment: this sounds very similar to what I do.  I have a class that reads a javascript directory, any .js files inside it are stripped of all comments, white space, minimizes, etc and then combined into 1 single file and gzipped.  Anytime any of the files change, the script will rebuild the big script automaticly, works well because the users always get a cached version.  This sounds like what you are doing as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are trying to save the overhead on the server of having to gzip the javascript package on every request? If that is the intention, this is not the proper way to accomplish that. You need to indicate that the file is being transferred with gzip compression in the header, as such:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 04 Dec 2003 16:15:12 GMT
Server: Apache/2.0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Cache-Control: max-age=300
Expires: Thu, 04 Dec 2003 16:20:12 GMT
X-Guru: basic-knowledge=0, general-knowledge=0.2, complete-omnipotence=0.99
Content-Length: 1533
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

notice `Content-Encoding: gzip`

In any case, concatenating and compressing your javascript is always a good idea, as long as you do it right. I would also recommend using some form of JS minification prior to compression as it will improve you post-compressed size

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's such a good idea if you plan on having returning visitors - and I assume it's the case if you are developing a web app. Because everytime one of your js files is modified, you will force your users to download a huge file.

When your user comes to your app the first time, they are often quite forgiving if the loading time is a bit long. If you show them a nice introduction text, they will have something to read and/or look at while the scripts and various assets are loading. But if they have to wait for your huge script to be loaded everytime they come back because it's all-or-nothing, that will be considered poor UX.

If you don't need all the 20-30 files at first when the user loads your app, use a script loader to load them in the background.

If you do need those 20-30 files, try to aggregate them in 10 or so files, trying to aggregate those that have the highest probability to be updated together.

As for the gzip compression, your web server should handle that.

Comment: i wonder, how often do you change your js files? I change them about once every 3-6 months so i dont actually see a problem if i'd rebuild that cache a few months apart. Even rebuilding it daily is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its a good ideea.

What i'm doing is to use a custom php function like `load_script($filename)` that adds that file to a "load queue". And at the end of the page i insert another function `generate_js_script()` that parsers these queued scripts, generates a big js file(i guess i could run a minimizer at this point) and writes it to disk with a unique filename. The the function simply generates the `<script>` tag so the browser knows to load this "big" js file. 
This way i dont bother with customized `header()` calls, and other weird things that are caused problems with some browsers and their caching algorithm in the past.

This way, i could simply use a `.htaccess` directive to tell the server to serve all js files compressed(if the browser supports it ), so i wont have to do it in php.
The trick about this kind of caching is not to re-generate too often. I use some kind of hashing to take care of this.